# How to convert Future[Vector[Either[Exception, A]]] to Future[Vector[A]]

Tags: scala

I want to convert Future[Vector[Either[Exception, A]]] to Future[Vector[A]], not sure if there's a easier way than doing:

```
for {
      pc <- aConfig
    } yield for {
      p <- pc
    } yield p match {
      case Right(p) => p
      case Left(e) => new RuntimeException(e)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty much the same as what you've got, just a little cleaner and more concise.

```
aConfig.map(_.map(_.fold(throw _, identity)))
```